# JS Filter links are moving page - not sure why

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple menu setup whereby all info is on the same page - just most is hidden until that tab is selected. The filter JS I'm using works great for this but for some reason (in CHROME only), when the menu item is clicked (eg, Location, Help), the screen shoots up a few hundred pixels (displays the selected info just fine though). Strangely, this happens only when the page is refreshed and the item is clicked for the first time. After that, everything works great!

Below is the pertinent code but to see it in action, see [test site](http://www.southsideurbanmarket.com/)

The JS I'm using for the filter is:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav a').click(function() {
        $('#nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','');

        $('#content div').each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).show().removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

with the HTML menu and info as:

```
<ul id=nav>
<a href="#" class="current"><li>Mission</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Location</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Help</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Vendors</li></a>        
</ul>


        <div id=content>
        <div class=mission>
            <img src="./images/roosters.jpg">
            <h2>The Mission</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div class=location>
            <img src="./images/old_market.jpg">
            <h2>Our Location</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div class=help>
            <img src="./images/helpers.jpg">
            <h2>Get Involved</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>

        <div class=vendors>
            <img src="./images/artisans.jpg">
            <h2>Our Vendors</h2>
            <p>...</p>
        </div>          

    </div>
```

Comment: Your html markup is invalid. Only `<li />` elements are allowed as direct childs of `<ul />` or `<ol />`

Answer (score 0):

It's the `href="#"` in your anchor tags, those are pointing to the top of the page. You probably want to add a `preventDefault()` to your click handler. Read all about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Comment: where would I put that? I added it right under the "return false;" but it did nothing. Plus, when clicked, it doesn't go all the way to the top of the page, just some of the way.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you had `return false;` in there, the source of the problem seems to be elsewhere, setting up a fiddle now to play with it.

Comment: thanks! I've swapped the href="#" with "javascript:", "javascript:void(0)", etc and no change.

Comment: Do you have any content following your `#content` div? I think what's happening is that when those inner divs get set to be hidden, the page isn't moving up per se, the content is just moving down. I set up a Fiddle and if I add a `div` with content following what you had, the problem goes away.

Comment: I don't, just the "push" div for the sticky footer and then the footer. I'll try your suggestion real quick...

Comment: My original answer is way off the mark, but it's definitely related to the hiding/showing of those divs, just can't completely grok what is happening there.

Comment: Got it! I don't have need for any extra content after the #content div but I fixed it by just adding a min-height fallback. Thanks @ultranaut, you got me on the right track.

Comment: Yeah, the way your click handler is showing/hiding the divs, in instances where the current div gets hidden before the new div gets shown, that first div goes away, page readjusts itself accordingly, and then the new div shows up, and the page stays where it now is. So maintaining the height like you're doing should fix it.